# check if a value matches a key in a list of custom array elements and retrieve its value

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, filter

I have an two arrays of custom data in Swift. I'd like to find the object that contains value of dictionaries whose "Destination" equals to the 'PlaceId' in second array. here is the structs with some data just to show what they will look like.

```
struct FlightInfo {
var minPrice = "648"
var carrier = "Canada Air ways"
var destination = "973973"
var origin = "983983"
}


struct PlaceData {
var cityName = "Melbourne"
var name = "Melbourne"
var cityId = "MEL"
var type = "blah"
var countryName = "Australia"
var placeId = 983983
}
```

I got this thus far:

```
    let destId = flightsArray[indexPath.row].destination as String
    let results = listOfPlaces.filter { $0.placeId == Int(destId) }
```

but no cigar. How can I end up with something like following as the final result:

```
cell.destinationLabel.text = results.placeID
```

Comment: `$0.placeId` is a `String`, and you try to compare with a `Int` (`Int(destId)`). That could be your issue. `{ $0.placeId == destId }` instead?

Comment: try `as Int` in the first line of code and then change `Int(destId)`  to `destId` in the second line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would reconsider using Dictionary as model objects. It is much reliable to use `structs`, `classes` and `enums` instead.
Thus, your model would look similar to this:

```
enum FlightType: String {
    case a = "A"
    case b = "B"
}

enum PlaceType: String {
    case station = "station"
    case port = "port"
}

struct Flight {
    var name: String
    var destinationId: Int
    var type: FlightType
}

struct Place {
    var identifier: Int
    var title: String
    var type: PlaceType
}
```

Assuming you have arrays like this:

```
let flights = [
    Flight(name: "Trenton", destinationId: 403, type: .a),
    Flight(name: "Houston", destinationId: 288, type: .a),
    Flight(name: "Boston", destinationId: 244, type: .a)
]

let places = [
    Place(identifier: 111, title: "Leslie", type: .station),
    Place(identifier: 228, title: "Mary", type: .station),
    Place(identifier: 684, title: "Joe", type: .station),
    Place(identifier: 288, title: "Paul", type: .station),
    Place(identifier: 465, title: "Stephanie", type: .station),
    Place(identifier: 569, title: "Steve", type: .station),
    Place(identifier: 663, title: "Doug", type: .station)
]
```

You can get flight's destination title like this:

```
let destinationId = flights[indexPath.row].destinationId
let destinationTitle = places.filter{ $0.identifier == destinationId }.first?.title
```

Comment: Thanks, in my code they are structs. but i do like the was you organized them into enums as well. I might do that but all in the same struct.

Answer (score 0):

Taking your definitions to rough code, this will give you what you want:

Note that in your example you gave out other objects, so just convert it to your needs.

```
let flightsArray =
    [[ "Name": "Trenton", "destination": 403, "type":"A" ],
    [ "Name": "Houston", "destination": 288, "type":"A" ],
    [ "Name": "Boston", "destination": 244, "type":"A" ]]

var placedata = [
    ["PlaceId": "111", "title": "Leslie", "type": "station"],
    ["PlaceId": "228", "title": "Mary", "type": "station"],
    ["PlaceId": "684", "title": "Joe", "type": "station"],
    ["PlaceId": "288", "title": "Paul", "type": "station"],
    ["PlaceId": "465", "title": "Stephanie", "type": "station"],
    ["PlaceId": "569", "title": "Steve", "type": "station"],
    ["PlaceId": "663", "title": "Doug", "type": "station"],
]

for flightAt in flightsArray
{
    let places = placedata.filter({ Int($0["PlaceId"]!)! == (flightAt["destination"] as! NSNumber).intValue })

    for place in places
    {
        print ("\(place["title"])")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try it

```
let flightsArray =
    [[ "Name": "", "destination": 403, "type":"A" ],
[ "Name": "", "destination": 288, "type":"A" ],
[ "Name": "", "destination": 244, "type":"A" ]] as [[String : Any]]
var placedata = [
    ["PlaceId": "111", "title": "Leslie", "type": "station"],
    ["PlaceId": "228", "title": "Mary", "type": "station"],
    ["PlaceId": "684", "title": "Joe", "type": "station"],
    ["PlaceId": "288", "title": "Paul", "type": "station"],
    ["PlaceId": "465", "title": "Stephanie", "type": "station"],
    ["PlaceId": "569", "title": "Steve", "type": "station"],
    ["PlaceId": "663", "title": "Doug", "type": "station"],
]
let destId = flightsArray[indexPath.row]["destination"] as! Int
let results = placedata.filter { $0["PlaceId"]! as String == "\(destId)" }
cell.destinationLabel.text = results[0]["placeID"]
```